# iReport : How to design report from OLAP cube with multiple dimension and calculated measure in iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, mdx, olap, olap-cube

I have designed OLAP cube in *Jaspersoft OLAP Designer*. Now I have imported this Cube in *iReport* by making OLAP connection.

I am tested my result set using following MDX query

```sql
select  HealthCheckStatusD.Members ON AXIS(0),
{ChannelD.Members} ON AXIS(1), {HealthCheckDateD.Members } ON AXIS(2) from  CubeReport2 where Measures.[Patient]
```

***Also modified version of above query:***

```sql
select  HealthCheckStatusD.Members ON Columns,
CrossJoin(ChannelD.Members,HealthCheckDateD.Members) ON Rows from  CubeReport2
```

As far as I know both queries are logically same.

Logical cube structure is as follows:

```
--Cube
----HealthCheckDateDimension
----ChannelDimension
----HealthCheckStatusDimension
---------PatientMeasure
```

Now I want to prepare report in *iReport* in the way I am getting result from MDX query.

How to do that with *iReport*? I tried using crosstabs in *iReports* but when I specify above MDX query I am not getting any way to specify measure in the crosstabs.

Is there any another approach in *iReport* of designing reports for OLAP views? kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Result from MDX and Report structure are two different thing. I am assuming that you want to construct a cross tab report from MDX results with some horizontal and vertical grouping (you can have chart based and flat table based report also),

1. You need to load the field in the report. The way to do it is to
   select the query editor window and specify your query over there
       (next to zoom icons).
2. For simplicity sake, place your cross tab in
       summary section of the page (cross tab in detail section need
       special handling- work around). It will than allow you to select the
       horizontal and vertical grouping.
3. It then allows you to select the measure for the crosstab. You can also choose to 
   show row wise and column wise totals.
4. If you are using inbuild Mondrian Olap engine, than you should be able to see your report in preview pane.

Let me know how it goes.

Gaurav J

Comment: As I mentioned above my MDX query : select  HealthCheckStatusD.Members ON Columns,
CrossJoin(ChannelD.Members,HealthCheckDateD.Members) ON Rows from  CubeReport2 .. Here the implicit measure is count of Patient.. That works in OLAP Designer.. but how to specify measure in iReport??